# receiving input using fgets in assembly

Tags: assembly, io, x86, user-input, fgets

I got a problem with reading to a buffer using fgets in assemmbly.
I know that the numbers are equal to the ASCII value ATM , and its not the problem. I cant get the real value of the user input.
Before using fgets I am required to print the string: "calc:" and i think its messing with my real input.

```
section .rodata

        CALC:   DB "calc:" , 10 , 0         ;format string 

section .bss
        buffer:         resb 80             ;store my input
```

;....more data, not relevant

```
push CALC                       ;push string to stuck
call printf             
add esp, 4                      ;remove pushed argument

push dword [stdin]              ;fgets need 3 param
push dword 80                   ;max lenght
push dword buffer               ;input buffer
call fgets
add esp, 12                     ;remove 3 push from stuck

mov ecx, [buffer]              ;THIS IS FOR GDB
stop_here:
```

Now, the problem is that the value in buffer isn't what the user put in the input. when I used the GDB debugger for better understanding I got the following results:

```
input 0  --> ecx value is: 2608  (should be 48)
input 1  --> ecx value is: 2609  (should be 49)
input 10 --> ecx value is: 667697 (should be 48+49)
input 34 --> ecx value is: 668723 (should be 51+52)
```

EDIT:
I tryed using gets instead, and now it works!
can someone PLEASE explain to me why?!

EDIT- 5 years later - I can't believe I knew this much assembly back then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` stores the terminating line feed into the buffer as well, and since you are loading 4 bytes into `ecx`, you will also see that.

```
2608 = 0A30 hex = '0' LF
667697 = 0A3031 hex = '1' '0' LF
```

(Remember that x86 is little endian.)

Comment: hi, tanks for answer, it helps,

Comment: Yes, because `gets` does not place the line feed into the buffer :) See `man gets`: _gets() reads a line from stdin into the buffer pointed to by s until either a terminating newline or  EOF,  which  it replaces with a null byte_